# Bounds of integration

Tags: surface-integrals

A little bit rusty on the topic of surface integrals and perhaps some basic calculus after a while. A little help would be appreciated

Find the volume of the solid under the surface $$z=3x^{2}+y^{2}
$$ and above the region bounded by $$y=x$$ and $$y^{2}-y=x.$$

The main problem I'm facing is with the parabola. I've found the parabola to cut the y-intercept at $y=0$ and $y=1$. However, this does not square with the solutions I am looking at.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: It is helpful to draw pictures for these types of problems. You need to visualize how these surfaces intersect one another in order to find the bounds of your integrals.

Comment: @AlexG. I did but not exactly sure what am I missing.
Clearly, the parabola intercept the y-axis at y=0 and y=1. The equation y=x is just the straight line. 
I want the area bounded within this region.
But clearly, when I attempt to determine the point of intersection, I arrived at y=0 which is a contradiction so something is wrong somewhere.

Comment: I think you are missing that these are surfaces in three dimensional space, not just lines and parabolas. $y=x$ is a plane, and $y^2-y=x$ is a "parabola-shaped cylinder" or whatever you would call it. You need to see not only how these two intersect, but how they intersect with $z=3x^2+y^2$ as well.

Comment: @AlexG. I don't believe that we need to consider the "sides" of the plane $x=y$ and parabolic cylinder $x=y^2-y$.  The volume under the surface $z=3x^2+y^2$.  We need not see how they intersect with the surface of interest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might be easier here to view the region in the $x-y$ plane, which comprises the domain for the integral, having $y$ playing the role of the independent variable and having $x$ as a function of $y$.

The region in the $x-y$ plane is bounded from $x=y^2-y$ to $x=y$ as $y$ goes from $0$ to $2$.

Therefore, the volume integral is

$$V=\int_0^2\int_{y^2-y}^y(3x^2+y^2)dx\,dy$$

Can you finish?

Comment: Of course, trivial. Thank you!

Comment: @Mathematicing You're welcome!!  My pleasure.